# DAX column count latest record for each set of group with a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get Latest updated record which is bit tricky to retrieve using DAX column with power bi

Count -> Order Count based on Modified On(Datetime) with Ascending Order
Deleted -> a Flag set to be True for deleted record

| Id | Name | Modified On | Deleted | Count | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Charles | 09-11-2022 15:09:40 |  | 1 |  |
| 1 |  | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 | True | 2 |  |
| 1 | Charles M | 09-11-2022 20:39:40 |  | 3 | True |
| 2 | Charles | 09-11-2022 15:09:40 |  | 1 |  |
| 2 |  | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 | True | 2 |  |
| 2 | Charles M | 09-11-2022 20:39:40 |  | 3 |  |
| 2 |  | 09-11-2022 21:16:33 | True | 4 |  |
| 2 | charles m | 09-11-2022 21:18:33 |  | 5 |  |
| 3 | Dani | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 |  | 1 | True |
| 3 |  | 09-11-2022 21:16:33 | True | 2 |  |
| 4 | George | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 |  | 1 |  |
| 4 | George K | 09-11-2022 21:16:33 |  | 2 |  |

In the above example I wanted the **Result** column values as it is on above table.

explanation:

Here **Id** : 1, The record is two times created as well as deleted so the history of record will have four rows. I wanted the last updated record which is the **3rd row** and not the last record because the is **Deleted** flag is set to be True so there is no Name on it.
as so on for the second but Id:2
If the last insert on the record is not deleted then whole result column of the id should not return anything

(Id: 3)
In the third set there is there is no update on the record with this history table. the first row is created and second is for the deletion. so we should have to retrieve the first record which only have that data on Name field

Id: 4
There is no deletion operation happened so we don't want to get that record. the result columns should be empty

Thanks in advance

I have tried to get the latest record with

```
LatestDeletedRecord = 
VAR latest = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Column3]), ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Id]))
 RETURN IF('Table'[Column3] = latest && 'Table'[IsDeleted] = True,True)
```

Other than nothing I could,  I am new to DAX calculations

Comment: What is the difference between ID = 1 and ID = 2? They appear to be the same type of case but have different result column values.

Comment: The difference is for Id = 1 the last updated record was Deleted = True . but id =2 the last updated record not have Deleted set for True. whatever the record Id set will be the last record Deleted column should be True to get the Result True @Marcus

Comment: The last ID = 1 record is not deleted in your updated table. But I have inserted a new row that captures this last deleted row for ID = 1 for my edited solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If your requirements change, you should perhaps post a new question instead of editing your existing question :-)

With your altered requirements you can use this calculated column:

```
Result = 
VAR _max = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( 'Table'[Modified On] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Id] )
    )
VAR _max_is_deleted = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Deleted] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Id] ) , 
        'Table'[Modified On] = _max 
    )
VAR _max_mod = 
    // Calculate the maximum modified date where name is not deleted
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( 'Table'[Modified On] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Id] ) , 
        'Table'[Name] <> ""
    )
RETURN
IF ( 
    // For rows where ID has an associated deletion AND modified is max with name
    _max_is_deleted 
        && [Modified On] = _max_mod,
    // Return "True"
    "True" 
)
```

Gives your desired result:

[image]

Comment: is that 'Table'[Deleted] column is String/Text type

Comment: for me its True/False Data type

Comment: thanks for your support on this .. your code is working fine

Comment: Should be fine with either - depends on your requirements. The data type of `'Table'[Deleted]` shouldn’t matter for this calculation I believe?

Comment: Why did you revoke acceptance of the answer? Strange.

Comment: one more scenario we missed out which is "If the last insert on the record is not deleted then whole result column of the id should not return anything "

Comment: for the second set the if the last record is not set for deleted flag then the whole group is not to be true ... this scenario we missed out

Comment: i have updated in the table structure above

Comment: Really sorry about mentioning this delay scenario but it should be there to complete my requirement. apologize me on this